# Cannot read property 'category' of undefined - error trying to use data from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get some data from the state to display. If I console.log it within `componentDidMount` I get exactly what I want but if I try to use it inside `render()` then gives me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

```
class ProductList extends Component {
  state = {
    products: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const catslug = this.props.match.params.catslug;
    const { data: products } = await getCatProducts(catslug);
    this.setState({ products: products });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Container fluid={true} className="product_header mb-5">
          <h1 className="product_header-text">
            {this.state.products[0].category.name}
          </h1>
        </Container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes there are chances products can be empty(like before fetching data) DidMount will get called once component will render and first render it will throw error because there is nothing inside products state that is empty array.
You can handle this way.

```
<Container fluid={true} className="product_header mb-5">
          <h1 className="product_header-text">
            {this.state.products[0] && this.state.products[0].category.name}
          </h1>
</Container>
```

Also you can add loading state and isEmpty state so that after api callback you can check data is empty so that you can show empty state component.

Explanation why it is happening:

`products[0]` will give `undefined`

if we check

`typeof undefined` that returns `'undefined'` i.e. it is not object

so in that case we were checking

`products[0].category` that means `undefined.category`

So JS will throw error always.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

Comment: Ah. I thought that putting the empty array in the state initially would handle that? `state = {
    products: [],
  };`

Comment: No `products[0]` will be undefined and type of undefined is "undefined" so you can use that as object so it will throw error always.